# Scope and accessor functions with second constructors?

Tags: c++, function, class

So basically my professor gave us the class student and told us to implement all functions and write a main for the function. I am trying to do this but I am having trouble figuring out the errors that are arising, in all of my  accessor functions it is telling me that nCredits, gpa, and s aren't declared in the scope. I assume this has something to do with the second constructor, but I am not sure what exactly the issue is. The second constructor and the displayStRec function were also provided to our class, I just don't know how to do this program with the variables in the member function being renamed as they have been.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class student
{
            public:
                            student();
                            student(string s, double gpa, int nCredits);
                            ~student(); //destructor
                            void changeCredits(int nCredits);

                            int getCredits();

                            void changeGPA(double gpa);

                            double getGPA();

                            void displayStRec();

            private:
                            string name;
                            double GPA;
                            int credits;
};

student::student()
{
            name = "No name yet";
            GPA = 0;
            credits = 0.0;
            cout << "Default constructor entered!" << endl;
}
student::student(string s, double gpa, int nCredits)
{
            name = s;
            GPA = gpa;
            credits = nCredits;
            cout << "Second constructor entered!" << endl;
}

void student::changeCredits(int nCredits){
 cout << "Enter credits earned:" << endl;
 cin >> nCredits;
}

int student::getCredits(){
return nCredits;
}

void student::changeGPA(double gpa){
 cout << "Enter GPA: " << endl;
 cin >> gpa;
}

double student::getGPA(){
 return gpa;
}

void student::displayStRec()
{
        cout << "   Name: " << s <<endl;
        cout << "    GPA: " << gpa <<endl;
        cout << "Credits: " << nCredits <<endl;
}

student::~student()
{
            cout << "Destructor entered!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
            student s1,s2("John",4.0,42);
            s2.changeCredits(nCredits);
            s2.getCredits();
            s2.changeGPA(gpa);
            s2.getGPA();
            s2.displayStRec();
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're spelling the variable name wrong. You have a private `credits` member, but no `nCredits` member. Look immediately after `private`.

Comment: You should use member variables instead.

Comment: sorry c++ is case sensitive and doesn't read minds

Comment: I know that I have credits and nCredits, but thats how the assignment is supposed to be. The second constructor was given to us, and it changes credits = nCredits, etc. The member function prototypes were also given to use, so I have to use the renamed data types that are giving me errors. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: but you don't have a member data `nCredits` and `gpa`

Comment: Right, that's why I am confused, is it even possible to do it this way? I downloaded the code from my professor, this is 100% how it was setup by him, but I just can't seem to figure how to do it with the renamed variables.

Comment: nono never! one thing what do you really want to do??

Comment: Don't understand your reply.

Comment: another thing what is `cin >> gpa`? for? you input a local variable and don't use it. `GPA` is not `gpa`

Comment: I was attempting to have user input for the gpa, but it's not working so that can be taken out, my concern here is how to make this program work using the nCredits, s, and gpa variables as replacements for the private variables.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is `student s("runesbane",0.0,0)`... get it??? sorry couldn't resist

Comment: No need to be rude. I downloaded this code this way and attempting to make sense of it and am reaching out for help. I figured it was not do able this way, but I decided to reach out to people who have more knowledge in this subject for assistance, not to be mocked.

Answer (score 1):

You've got three variables that you're using that aren't declared.  I'll hit them one by one.

### Missing s

```
void student::displayStRec()
{
        cout << "   Name: " << s <<endl;
        cout << "    GPA: " << gpa <<endl;   
        cout << "Credits: " << nCredits <<endl;  
}
```

In this function, you are trying to output some variable `s` that isn't declared within the scope of displayStRec.  You used `s` in the constructor to initialize the name, copying it to member variable `name`.  Well, `s` is gone now!  But `name` persists for the lifetime of the object.  So, just use `name` instead.

```
void student::displayStRec()
{
        cout << "   Name: " << name <<endl;  //Change it here
        cout << "    GPA: " << gpa <<endl;
        cout << "Credits: " << nCredits <<endl;
}
```

### Missing nCredits and gpa

In your main function you're using two variables that aren't declared.

```
int main()
{
            student s1,s2("John",4.0,42);
            s2.changeCredits(nCredits);  //What nCredits?
            s2.getCredits();
            s2.changeGPA(gpa);           //What gpa?
            s2.getGPA();
            s2.displayStRec();
            return 0;
}
```

This leads to the question... what are you trying to change their credits **to**?  What are you trying to change their gpa **to**?  In other words, shouldn't your program have input parameters?  Perhaps somewhere in your assignment your professor told you what values to provide.  You will need constants of some kind, or you will need to gather user input from `cin`.

### Oh and by the way, this makes zero sense

```
void student::changeGPA(double gpa){
    cout << "Enter GPA: " << endl;
    cin >> gpa;
}
```

This function will accept user input and update the variable `gpa`, which is declared in local scope and immediately discarded.  Not very useful.

Also, it accepts an input value (`double gpa`) but also collects input from `cin`.  Why do both?  Can't update it to two values at the same time!

My guess is that is supposed to update the object's GPA, which is declared in member scope.  Like this:

```
void student::changeGPA(){
    cout << "Enter GPA: " << endl;
    cin >> GPA;
}
```

or

```
void student::changeGPA(double gpa){
    GPA = gpa;
}
```

### Conclusion

One of the following must be true:

1. You copied the code examples incorrectly
2. The professor gave you a trick question
3. The professor is sort of clueless or perhaps a bit overworked

Comment: Understand your second point well, thank you. However, the void displayStRec() function was given to us, is there anyway to actually do this program using those instead of the private variables?

Comment: Unless `s` is a member variable or global variable, the function as written will never compile.

Comment: @runesbane It's not uncommon for teachers to give students broken code. I got it several times in my courses.

Comment: @John Since you've posted, you might as well point out the issue with `changeGPA`.

Comment: I wonder changeGpa takes a parameter then doesn't do anything with it and instead input again GAP??!!!

Comment: @Raindrop7 It should either not pass in anything, or not ask the user directly. It's not clear what the intent is.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I suppose that is possible, but we were doing this in class today and he got up to that point in the program and told us to finish the rest at home for class tomorrow, but it seems that it cannot be done that way he wants, so I guess I will just do it in my own way with the private variables.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes that is it and the same thing with changeCredits

Comment: @runesbane The function, as John shows is entirely broken. I worry if your teacher intended this code.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone ahead and removed the sloppy second constructor functions my professor is trying to force on us and this program now works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class student
{
            public:
                            student();
                            student(string s, double gpa, int nCredits);
                            ~student(); //destructor
                            void changeCredits();

                            int getCredits();

                            void changeGPA();

                            double getGPA();

                            void displayStRec();

            private:
                            string name;
                            double GPA;
                            int credits;
};

student::student()
{
            name = "No name yet";
            GPA = 0;
            credits = 0.0;
            cout << "Default constructor entered!" << endl;
}

student::student(string s, double gpa, int nCredits)
{
            name = s;
            GPA = gpa;
            credits = nCredits;
            cout << "Second constructor entered!" << endl;
 }

 void student::changeCredits(){
 cout << "Enter credits earned: ";
 cin >> credits;
 }

 int student::getCredits(){
   return credits;
 }

 void student::changeGPA(){
  cout << "Enter GPA: ";
  cin >> GPA;
 }

double student::getGPA(){
 return GPA;
 }

void student::displayStRec()
{
         cout << "   Name: " << name <<endl;
        cout << "    GPA: " << GPA <<endl;
        cout << "Credits: " << credits <<endl;
}

student::~student()
{
            cout << "Destructor entered!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
            student s1,s2("John",4.0,42);
            s2.changeCredits();
            s2.getCredits();
            s2.changeGPA();
            s2.getGPA();
            s2.displayStRec();
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mix between double and int: `credits = 0.0` and `gpa = 0`

Answer (score 0):

here is a suggested solution however I don't know what your teacher orders:

!: add string to inclusion

2: use only member data not non members

3: either make changeCredits and changeGPA take 0 argument and inside it ask for inputs or input outside and and pass to it.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class student
{
    public:
        student();
        student(string s, double gpa, int nCredits);
        ~student(); //destructor

        void   changeCredits();
        int    getCredits();
        void   changeGPA();
        double getGPA();
        void   displayStRec();

    private:
        string name;
        double GPA;
        int    credits;
};

student::student() : 
    name("No name yet"), GPA(0.0), credits(0)
{
    cout << "Default constructor entered!" << endl;
}

student::student(string s, double gpa, int nCredits) : 
    name(s), GPA(gpa), credits(nCredits)
{
    cout << "Second constructor entered!" << endl;
}

void student::changeCredits()
{
    cout << "Enter credits earned:" << endl;
    cin  >> credits;
    cout << endl;
}

int student::getCredits()
{
    return credits;
}

void student::changeGPA()
{
    cout << "Enter GPA: " << endl;
    cin >> GPA;
    cout << endl;
}

double student::getGPA()
{
    return GPA;
}

void student::displayStRec()
{
    cout << "   Name: " << name <<endl;
    cout << "    GPA: " << GPA <<endl;
    cout << "Credits: " << credits <<endl;
}

student::~student()
{
    cout << "Destructor entered!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    student s1, s2("John", 4.0, 42);
    s2.changeCredits();
    s2.getCredits();
    s2.changeGPA();
    s2.getGPA();
    s2.displayStRec();

    return 0;
}
```